# How can I print \" In C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to print `\"Hey\"` in the Console But when I run it It just print the `"Hey"` without `\` and when i put another `\` in the beginning and `\` in end it says theres an Error

Comment: `"\\\"Hey\"\\"`

Comment: Also you can use `@"\"` in order to print escape characters

Comment: Alternatively `@"\""Hey""\"` where the backslashes don't need to be escaped, but now the double quotes do, with double double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the `"` as well as the `\`. Both should be escaped with a backslash itself. Your final result should look something like:
`Console.WriteLine("\\\"Hey\\\"");`